# Grep everything between two special character patterns

Tags: regex, grep

I am having trouble figuring out how to grep the characters between two special character patterns.
Specifically I need to grep everything between the first __ (double underscore) and the second __ I could use sed to convert them to spaces then cut the column, but that seems a bit unnecessary and messy.

My data looks something like this....

```
364__spc__spc__1334
608__aac(3)-Ik__aac(3)-Ik__1927
13__tet(S)__tet(S)_1__1102
```

The result I need is...

```
spc
aac(3)-Ik
tet(S)
```

Thanks in advance to anyone with suggestions.

Comment: Which programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with `awk`

```
awk -F'__' '{print $2}' filename
```

---

```
$ cat filename
364__spc__spc__1334
608__aac(3)-Ik__aac(3)-Ik__1927
13__tet(S)__tet(S)_1__1102

$ awk -F'__' '{print $2}' filename
spc
aac(3)-Ik
tet(S)
```

Comment: Quite easily with `grep` too! `;)`

Comment: Nice Answer with grep:)

Comment: Nice and neat, easier syntax than grep - Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for Java:

```
String s = "608__aac(3)-Ik__aac(3)-Ik__1927".replaceAll(".*?__(.*?)__.*", "$1");
```

PS: If you want to match several strings with this regex, consider creating an instance of [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for performances reason (regex compiled one time, used several times).

And another using `sed`:

```
echo "608__aac(3)-Ik__aac(3)-Ik__1927" | sed 's/.*\?__\(.*?\)__.*/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

**`grep`** has an option for this. From the man page:

> -o, --only-matching
>                Prints only the matching part of the lines.

```
$ cat file
364__spc__spc__1334
608__aac(3)-Ik__aac(3)-Ik__1927
13__tet(S)__tet(S)_1__1102
```

```
$ grep -o '__[^_]*__' file
__spc__
__aac(3)-Ik__
__tet(S)__
```

Comment: But @Lel needed `spc` and `aac(3)-Ik` as results (i.e. without surrounding '__')

Comment: This is what I was looking for, so thank you for this response. But yes I would need to use sed to remove the underscores. Could you possibly explain the usage of [^_] to define 'anything between'?
And how does this method determine whether to use the first or second pattern between the underscores? Thanks again

Comment: `[^_]*` means matching anything that is not an underscore. With `grep -o` it is going to match the first match only. You can extend with `-P` switch that would match all such entries in a line. Using the `-P` switch you can also remove the underscores.